# Rotary Cam Switch wiring help

Tags: switches, rotary

I am trying to wire this rotary cam switch to spin a DC motor forward and backwards based on the UP and DOWN setting. I am having a really hard time trying to figure out how to wire it. Can someone please give me some advice?  I have a power supply, DC pos and neg. And a motor. Which terminals should I plug the motor in, and which terminals should I plug the power supply in?

I have been trying to test with a multimeter, but the cam is spring-loaded so it is making things difficult.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminals 1 and 3 are the common terminals of a DPDT switch. The motor connects there. To form a bridge with the other throws of the switch, you need to connect the positive supply to 6 and the negative supply to 10. Connect a dual-color 2-lead LED with current limiter across 2 and 4 to give a power and direction indicator.